# Getting a token access to feature layer using Postman and Python

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis-rest-api, security

I am trying to query a feature server using postman as ESRI'S documentation:
https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/rest/get-an-access-token/

I have succesfully added the Authorization to the body of the request but I still get "token required"

The url that I am using to try to is

https://services1.arcgis.com/X1hcdGx5Fxqn4d0j/arcgis/rest/services/TiffanyTestingPrintData/FeatureServer/0/query

[image: generating the token by following the guide]

Later on, I would like to use the token for testing using the requests library. I don't know how I can pass this the token that is generated by the api. I would like to query various fields and pass it to an update method.

Answer (score -1):

I think you did not follow the instructions carefully. Try populating the fields like in the image below.

[image]

You can then generate a python code by clicking on the "Code" below the Save button and selecting Python --> Requests.

Comment: Well that's not what I am trying do. I am trying to use the ouath token so that I can pull data from my server. Perhaps I wasn't clear on that.